# Get related entry by its' column

Tags: entity-framework

I have tables called `Item` and `Metal`.

`Metal` has a foreign key called `ItemId` and a virtual property called `Item` that loads automatically and fetches appropriate item (thank you lazy loading :)).

`Item` on the other hand has no foreign keys related to `Metal` - and here's the issue.

I can't currently edit columns of the `Item` table, I can only modify the model in code.

What I'm trying to achieve is have access to `Metal` via `Item.Metal`, just as I have access to `Item` via `Metal.Item`.

Is there an attribute like `ForeignKey`, but one that allows specifying foreign key on the other table? Like:

```cs
[ForeignProxiedKey("ItemId")]
public virtual Metal Metal { get; set; }
```

PS: The relationship is 1 .. 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Item and Metal have one to one relationships and a metal cannot be present without an item, here is how you can mark MetalId as the primary and foreign key in Entity framework. By this you will have access to Metal via Item.Metal

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Metal Metal { get; set; }
}


public class Metal
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKey("Item")]
    public int MetalId { get; set; }

    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This resulted in both Item.Metal and Metal.Item being null.

Comment: Adding [ForeignKey] above `public virtual Item Item` solved the issue along with your code above. Thank you.